# I cannot customize the dind (Docker IN Docker)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The dind (Docker IN Docker) pulled from DockerHub works fine, but I cannot build the dind from scratch. 
I tried to build as follows.

My Docker version is 1.1.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/docker-library/docker
$ cd docker/
$ cd 1.1/
$ docker build -t docker:dind .
```

I could create a "dind" Docker image. After that I tried to run.

```
$ docker run -it --privileged --name test -d docker:dind
52e590b6636b3726bbe9774627f4424c2b9f8958a745d57c27d04cbec77a2d7b
$ docker run -it --rm --link test:docker docker run -it ubuntu bash
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The dind did not work well.

So, I tried to customize from the dind pulled from Docker Hub.

```
$ docker pull docker:dind
$ docker run -it docker:dind ash
/ # exit
$ docker commit d508c2fd7131 docker:dind
sha256:f20e0314f996fe9f66806df47c1bdff956c84d11a6bfe2ff66279bee968323ec
$ docker run -it --privileged --name test -d docker:dind
d877c1993275fd4039b749f52d60a3095d40d52e13255c4fd88a319ca7ec306a
$ docker run -it --rm --link test:docker docker run -it ubuntu bash
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

It also had same problem. I just run the "dind" on Docker and exit immediately.
I cannot understand why I cannot customize the "dind" image.
Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: All the image-related steps look fine. I think the problem is with your `docker-machine`. Make sure to run `eval "$(docker-machine env machine_name)"` first.

Comment: I have not used any docker machines. So, 'docker-machine ls' shows no machine.

Comment: I think "dind" is independent of docker machine.

Comment: what OS are you using? is the docker service running? `$ sudo service docker stop`, 
`$ sudo service docker start`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
docker run --privileged -d --name test docker:dind
docker exec -it test docker version
docker commit test mydind
```

You can use mydind image